# Trouble Displaying Radio Button Text With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

HAML

```
%body
%div.container
  %section#questions
    %form
      %label#questionLabel
        %input(type="radio" id="question1" value="") 
        %input(type="radio" id="question2" value="") 2
        %input(type="radio" id="question3" value="") 
        %input(type="radio" id="question4" value="") 4
        %div(style="clear:both")
        %input(type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit")
```

JavaScript

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
$("#question1").val(1);
$("#question1").text("1");
```

})

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to change the text of a radio button when I click a button. I posted my HAML and not HTML because I feel like that might have something to do with it.

When I put the numbers in directly into the HAML like I did with #question2 and #question4, the text shows up on the page like it should. However, when I try to add text via jQuery, nothing shows up. I can see it in the DOM in Dev Tools, but not on the actual page. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`text()` will not works here, you need to update the `textNode` immediately after the `radio`. Use `nextSibling` to get textnode and update value using `nodeValue`

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
  $("#question1")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = '1';
  $("#question1").vav("1");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="question1" value="">
<input type="radio" id="question2" value="">
<input id=submitButton vlaue=submit type=button>
```